# Why the following reciprocal queries have different performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

While reading the book "Graph Databases" by Oreilly, the author claims that query A is less computationally intensive than query B but I can't seem to spot the difference.

Particularly, it presents the following schema:
[image: Simple join-table arrangement for recording friendships]

Below, I present the two queries along with the author comments:

**Query A**: (Who are Bob's friends?)

```
SELECT p1.Person
FROM Person p1 JOIN
     PersonFriend
     ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p1.ID JOIN
     Person p2
     ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p2.ID
WHERE p2.Person = 'Bob'
```

> This isn’t a particularly expensive or difficult query, because it constrains the number of rows under consideration using the filter WHERE Person.person='Bob'.

**Query B**: (Who is friends with Bob?)

```
SELECT p1.Person
FROM Person p1 JOIN
     PersonFriend
     ON PersonFriend.PersonID = p1.ID JOIN
     Person p2
     ON PersonFriend.FriendID = p2.ID
WHERE p2.Person = 'Bob'
```

> This reciprocal query is still easy to implement, but on the database side it’s more expensive, because the database now has to consider all the rows in the PersonFriend table.

My understanding is that in both queries the filtering constrains the number of rows under consideration, though this explanation is given only for the first query. Am I missing something or the claim is false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this claim is false . . . at least in the sense that the database can be structured so the two have essentially the same performance.  A table such as `personfriend` would want indexes on both `(personid)` and `(friendid)` (or better yet, `(personid, friendid)` and `(friendid, personid)`).

With both indexes, both queries can be optimized to use one of the indexes.

There *are* database structures where the statement would be true.  So, there might be more verbiage that supports the statement.  For instance, if there is only one index or just a primary key declaration, then the two queries are not equivalent in terms of performance.

But having the indexes can give them essentially the same execution plan.

Comment: The author doesn't actually mentions anything about indexes. If we had index on only one of the two columns of PersonFriend table then I can understand why there would be a performance difference. Though, in the simple case that there are no indexes whatsoever the performance of those queries would be the same, right?

Comment: @dimlek . . . Without indexes (or a unique constraint), they would have equivalent execution plans -- in all likelihood.